# red5 as3 rtmp live stream( sent from xuggle) subscriber example?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, red5, rtmp, live-streaming

Iam sending an rtmp stream from xuggle ffmpeg following the red5 wiki http://red5wiki.com/wiki/Live_streaming .

```
fmpeg -i test.flv -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv -re rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/oflaDemo/streams/liveStream
```

I have two instances on my stage. a video class instance to which i am attaching the stream after a successful net connect, and an FVLplayback instance to which i am giving the rtmp url as its source.

I am unable to subscribe to the stream. some relevant code bits.

```
private var rtmpURL:String = "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/oflaDemo"; // connection url

        myplayer.isLive=true; // flvplayback instance on stage
        myplayer.autoPlay=true;
        myplayer.source='rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/oflaDemo/liveStream';
                  // video class instance
        var video:Video = new Video  ;
        video.attachNetStream(stream);
        stream.play("liveStream");
        addChild(video);
```

what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was with the actual red 5 version rc1 windows installer, the above code works just fine when that is fixed. http://wiki.red5.org/wiki/1_0_RC1